# Question about writing integrals as a sum of integrals?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

So the question that is given is as follows:

Write the integral as a sum of integrals without absolute values and evaluate

$$ \int_{-2}^3 |x^3| \, dx$$

Can someone help me figure this out because I keep getting $20.25$ or $\dfrac{81}{4}$ but the answer is supposedly $24.25$ or $\dfrac{97}{4}$.

Comment: Hint: Where is $x^3$ positive, where is it negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $|x^3| = -x^3$ when $x \le 0$. We can therefore split the integral into two as follows:

$$\int_{-2}^3 |x^3| dx = \int_{-2}^0 |x^3| dx + \int_0^3 |x^3| dx = -\int_{-2}^0 x^3 dx + \int_0^3 x^3 dx = -\frac{x^4}{4}\bigg|_{-2}^0 + \frac{x^4}{4}\bigg|_0^3$$

$$= -\left(\frac{0}{4}-\frac{16}{4}\right) + \left(\frac{81}{4}-\frac{0}{4}\right) = \frac{16}{4}+\frac{81}{4} = \frac{97}{4}.$$